# Fetch node value containing escape characters using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I am using Java XML API to fetch a node value for a given XPath.
Here is the code I am using to fetch the node value for a given XPath

```
    final XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    final XPath xpath1 = factory.newXPath();
    xpath1.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(extractData(fileName));
    inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    String nodeValue = xpath1.evaluate(xpath, inputSource);
```

The xml file contains the node value as `Some&gt;data`
The node value I am expecting is `Some&gt;data` but the value that is returned from the above code is `Some>data`

Can any one help how to change the above code so that i get the node data as `Some&gt;data`

Comment: One is just the "non XML escaped" form of the other, why do you specifically want the XML escaped one?

Comment: I am writing some unit tests where i need to compare the node value that is exactly what is present in the xml file.

Comment: Well, yes, and here your XML API is doing the job correctly. Try and _write_ an XML file with the same structure and `"Some>data"` as the text content at exactly the same path: you will see that in the XML, it will become `"Some&gt;data"`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm using normal io package to search the text exists or not for my unit tests